# AngularJS : directives newbie

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm starting my great adventure with angular and wanted to ask a question regarding directives usage, as I am not 100% sure after seeing multiple tutorials.

I want to make a simple app giving you directions:

1) click a button, fire in the controller a function to get current position from navigator geolocation (i think no service is necessary for this, and this can stay in the controller?)

2) after getting the coordinates I have some information about the place, which should be shown to the user, and here is the question: Should there be a directive with template for binding these information from the scope and showing in the dom, or is it enough to use simply "ng-hide" (which is in fact a directive - sic!:)) on a div, fetch the information on a place with a service, bind it with the hidden div, and set "ng-hide" to false to display the dom containing place information.

The "ng-hide" variant seems easy, but is it the proper "angular way" or just bad practice of beginners?

Thank You for your time and help in advance:)

Comment: You don't need to reinvent the wheel every time. The default directives are there to be used :)
Go ahead with the `ng-show` / `ng-hide` directives.
As a rule of thumbs: keep it simple. Complexity will arise, eventually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO

1. You can put it in a service if you want to use that method from different controllers or for clean-code purpose.
2. I use directives when I want a specific behaviour or a group of controls that repeat along the application. If you are using basic html controls and you just need to display/hide I would use ng-hide.